# Parameterize the KEY match attribute in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Can key attribute match be parameterized like below?

```
<xsl:param name="contSet">bioSafety|radSafety|Person|animalSpecies</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="contSet1" select="concat('|',$contSet,'|')"/>
<xsl:param name="list1" select="review/original/*"/>
<xsl:param name="list2" select="review/*"/>
<xsl:param name="path1" select="concat('/review/original','/')"/>
<xsl:param name="path2" select="concat('/review','/')"/>
<xsl:param name="cond1" select="@addcomment = '1'"/>

<xsl:key name="original" match="review/original/*" use="local-name()"/>
<xsl:key name="current" match="review/*" use="local-name()"/>
```

I want like theis:

```
<xsl:key name="original" match="$path1" use="local-name()"/>
<xsl:key name="current" match="$path2" use="local-name()"/>
```

But it is not working.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in XSLT hold values, not expressions or patterns.

It doesn't help you now, but the next draft of XSLT 3.0 is likely to contain a feature that does what you want. You can define "static parameters" (whose value must be supplied at compile time) like this:

```
<xsl:param name="path1" static="yes" select="concat('/review/original','/')"/>
<xsl:param name="path2" static="yes" select="concat('/review','/')"/>
```

and then you can use these in "shadow attributes" in the stylesheet: any attribute starting with "_" is pre-evaluated at compile time as an attribute value template:

```
<xsl:key name="original" _match="{$path1}" use="local-name()"/>
<xsl:key name="current" _match="{$path2}" use="local-name()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. However, you *can* prepare several key elements in advance and parametrize the choice of the key, e.g:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key($keyname, 'somevalue')" />
```